# DartPad: How to get more information if the console only prints 'Script Error'?

Tags: flutter, dart

For example:
If I run this [App](https://dartpad.dev/c941a183f265ed77a344d47e7dae5542) in DartPad the console only says `Script Error`. How can I get more information (What is the exact error? Where is it located?, ...)?

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap your code inside the try-catch block and then print the error on the console.

For example,

```
try {
   Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ScreenTwo()));
} catch (e) {
   print(e);
}
```